# Google Speech + Natural Language pipeline

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-speech-api

I am trying to do the following:

I want to create the following pipeline (that will run on google cloud)

- I have a device : *raspberry pi* with microphone
- I send the audio from raspberry pi to google (**streaming: real-time**),
- It is transcribed to text (**Google Cloud Speech**)
- The text is analyzed (***Google Cloud Natural Language***)
- I do some post processing
- the result (of the processing) is returned to the Raspberry pi

I know that i could do speech recognition request, then with the result from the API, send it directly to Natural Language, etc

But I would like to know if such a pipeline is possible.
I tried with ***Google DataFlow***, and with ***Google App Engine***, but I couldn't find a way to make this kind of pipeline with them.

*Thank you*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only one device producing voice input, a simple solution such as this should be sufficient(replace image with audio and translation/vision api with speech/natural language apis):

[image]

Cloud storage can trigger cloud functions and in turn cloud function can use cloud pub/sub to trigger other cloud functions.

See this [link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/ocr) for details.

Comment: Hi, first thank you for your answer.
The main problem for me is to deal with "real-time" audio streaming. I do not see how to do it with google cloud functions. I do not want to send mp3 file, but to stream the output of a microphone directly to a cloud function and then do the rest of the pipeline.
Thank you,
Erwan

Comment: then you just need to implement a backend app for accepting such streams

Answer (score 0):

I think Google DataFlow is not right choice for the pipeline you are trying to build, mainly because you are not trying to build a analytics pipeline. I think it will look something like the [link here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/use-cases/serverless-application-backends) and go to the "Serverless IoT backends" section. Use the Cloud Function for pipe-lining all the processing and then return the result back to your device. Also look at the example [here](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/iot-device-to-device).
Although my response is quite broad, but hope it gives you some direction to try.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Functions is the way to go. Here is a demo app that makes use of Cloud Vision API, GMail API, PubSub and CloudFunctions to build an intelligent GMail Labelling service.

Architecture diagram
[image]

Link to the code: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-functions-gmail-nodejs

Link to the blogpost: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/adding-custom-intelligence-to-gmail-with-serverless-on-gcp

In your case, the architecture flow could look something like the below
1. Send audio from Raspberry Pi to Cloud Storage bucket
2. Use a Cloud Function to listen to changes in the Cloud Storage bucket ([Reference](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/storage))
3. Trigger a call from the Cloud Function to Cloud Speech API to transcribe the audio
4. Use one more Cloud Function to trigger a call to NLP API
5. Do post-processing and write it to the output bucket
6. Use a cloud function to listen to the output bucket and trigger a call to send the output back to Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your answer, and it helps me. But, I would like to stream audio (real-time) to a cloud function, not to send file and store it to a Cloud Storage bucket. Do you know the way to do ? 
Thank you,
Erwan

Comment: you will be able to process bytes in-memory within cloud functions using the below snippet.      bytestream = BytesIO(); blob.download_to_file(bytestream); bytestream.seek(0)